# Meteor accounts: Accounts.ui.config - Cannot read property 'config' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

in a new meteor project I added accounts-ui, accounts-password and accounts-google. I created a file called client/config.js, in which I placed the code:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestOfflineToken: {
    google: true
  },
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
});
```

as the [docs suggest](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_ui_config).

in the console of the browser, this throws a: 
`config.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined`

the funny thing is, that the code seems to be working; I get username and email as requested, and a google oauth thing in the loginButtons dialog.

So what to do about the ugly error? It looks like I put it in the wrong location or something. I also tried putting it in client/compatibility, but same result. What causes this?

Comment: I think you have to add the `accounts-ui` package for `accounts.ui` to exist.

Comment: thank you @MichelFloyd, of course I had that too. updated the question to include this information.

Comment: have you added the `service-configuration` package and set that up for google?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I also have the same problem. 
I can solve it by putting

```
import {Accounts} from 'meteor/accounts-base'
```

into client folder's 'main.js'.

Comment: “Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.”